# применение одной функции к всем возможным комбинациям датафреймов

Tags: r

У меня имеется ряд датафреймов с более чем одной переменной в нем. Мне необходимо найти все возможные комбинации которыми можно сгруппировать эти датафреймы и применить к одной из переменных одну и ту же функцию. В примере я применяю функцию рассчитывающую корреляцию. Далее я объединяю результаты комбинации каждой пары в общий фрейм в котором записан результат выполнения функции и то к какой паре он относится. Сейчас я делаю это довольно топорным способом (как в моем примере) и ищу способ выполнения этих операций с более высокой скоростью, без такого большого кода.

```
a <- data.table(c(1,2,3,4), c(5,6,7,8))
b <- data.table(c(2,3,4,5), c(6,7,8,9))
c <- data.table(c(3,4,5,6), c(7,8,9,10))


a_a <- cor(a$V1, a$V1)
a_b <- cor(a$V1, b$V1)
a_c <- cor(a$V1, c$V1)

b_a <- cor(b$V1, a$V1)
b_b <- cor(b$V1, b$V1)
b_c <- cor(b$V1, c$V1)

c_a <- cor(c$V1, a$V1)
c_b <- cor(c$V1, b$V1)
c_c <- cor(c$V1, c$V1)

total <- rbind(a_a, a_b, a_c, b_a, b_b, b_c, c_a, c_b, c_c)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если передаить несколько `data.table` в функцию `data.table`, то эти таблицы будут объединены с помозью `cbind`. В коде ниже мы используем аналогичный принцип, но с небольшой хитростью, чтобы получить удобные имена столбцов.

```r
> l <- list(a, b, c)
> setattr(l, "names", c("a", "b", "c"))
> x <- as.data.table(l)
> x
   a.V1 a.V2 b.V1 b.V2 c.V1 c.V2
1:    1    5    2    6    3    7
2:    2    6    3    7    4    8
3:    3    7    4    8    5    9
4:    4    8    5    9    6   10
> cor(x)
     a.V1 a.V2 b.V1 b.V2 c.V1 c.V2
a.V1    1    1    1    1    1    1
a.V2    1    1    1    1    1    1
b.V1    1    1    1    1    1    1
b.V2    1    1    1    1    1    1
c.V1    1    1    1    1    1    1
c.V2    1    1    1    1    1    1
```